Configuration of gitlab.yml for smoke and full tests using the pipeline schedules
I would like to set up tests that will fire on the gitlab pipline. I would like to split the tests in cypress so that smoke fires once a day and all tests once a week. I have configured pipeline schedules in gitlab by specifying a variable for daily and weekly.
The problem is that now the pipeline does not start (all the time: Checking pipeline status).
Are the rules defined correctly?
---
#--------#
# STAGES #
#--------#

stages:
  - test

#------#
# JOBS #
#------#

cypress:test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node-20.11.0-chrome-121.0.6167.184-1-ff-123.0-edge-121.0.2277.128-1
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $CI_SCHED_FREQ == "weekly"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
  parallel: 2
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - /root/.cache/Cypress
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn add mocha
    - yarn test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/reports/
    expire_in: 1 week

cypress:test:smoke:
  image: cypress/browsers:node-20.11.0-chrome-121.0.6167.184-1-ff-123.0-edge-121.0.2277.128-1
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $CI_SCHED_FREQ == "daily"'
      when: always
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - /root/.cache/Cypress
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn add mocha
    - yarn test:smoke
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/reports/
    expire_in: 1 week

I have tried different rules configurations but it did not help.

Did you set CI_SCHED_FREQ in your schedule?

Can you include what you have in your schedule?

I solved my problem, I had to simplify the rules and with the pipeline schedule everything works :
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $CI_SCHEDULE_TAG == "weekly"'
      when: always
    - when: never

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $CI_SCHEDULE_TAG == "daily"'
      when: always

